# Weird error in creating conda environment from yml file? (PackagesNotFoundError for the yml file itself)

Tags: yaml, anaconda

I'm reinstalling Conda after a PC factory reset and trying to re-create an old conda environment from a yml file that I created by

```
conda env export --prefix $path_to_old_env_dir > voice_dep.yml
```

The resulting yml file looks ok to me, here's what it looks like:

```
name: voiceeda
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - ca-certificates=2022.12.7=h5b45459_0
  - libsqlite=3.40.0=hcfcfb64_0
  - openssl=1.1.1s=hcfcfb64_1
  - pip=22.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python=3.9.13=h6244533_2
  - setuptools=66.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sqlite=3.40.0=hcfcfb64_0
  - tzdata=2022g=h191b570_0
  - ucrt=10.0.22621.0=h57928b3_0
  - vc=14.3=hb6edc58_10
  - vs2015_runtime=14.34.31931=h4c5c07a_10
  - wheel=0.38.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - pip:
      - anyio==3.6.2
      - argon2-cffi==21.3.0
      - argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
      - arrow==1.2.3
      ...
```

but when I try to run

```
conda create -n voiceeda -f voice_dep.yml
```

The following odd error occurs.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - voice_dep.yml
```

I'd understand if it wasn't finding a particular package, I can remove versions etc. if so, but why is it saying it can't find the yml file itself? I'm very confused, wondering if I missed a crucial setup step during conda installation or smth? I'm on Windows 10, and installed anaconda to a D drive (conda version 23.1.0 & Python 3.9.13.).

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
conda create -n voiceeda -f voice_dep.yml
```

You need to -

```
conda **env** create -n voiceeda -f voice_dep.yml
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain why